# Configure a SSO using ADFS and SAML

Tags: authentication, active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I'm new in the profesional world, and my boss just asked me to configure on an already existing website an SSO using ADFS ans SAML.

I tried looking online, but I have no idea what to do...
I know how to install ADFS in my AD, and that's it

Thank you for your help and your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very vague question. I doubt you can get a complete solution at one place.

First step will to exchanges the federation metadata between ADFS and your app.

1. Register your application as the relying party in ADFS. [know more.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/create-a-relying-party-trust#:%7E:text=In%20Server%20Manager%2C%20click%20Tools,manually%2C%20and%20then%20click%20Next.)
2. Consume ADFS federation metadata xml in your app.
3. Your application must be a SAML Service Provider. Means it must redirect to ADFS for authentication. It must expose the Assertion Consumer URL to ADFS.
4. Once ADFS provides the assertion, your app must be able to parse and sign-verify it.

There is lot more to it. Best way is to clone the existing [SAML projects on GIT](https://github.com/search?q=saml) and accommodate the source code in your existing app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'll try it and keep you updated